# Filling missing dates with latest value per user in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, generate-series

I have a table *dayload* that marks when a user's daily hours change.

```
| id | date       | user_id | hours |
| 1  | 2019-01-27 | 1       | 4     |
| 2  | 2019-02-01 | 1       | 8     |
| 3  | 2018-06-30 | 2       | 5     |
| 4  | 2018-07-02 | 2       | 8     |
```

So the table keeps track only of the changes. What I would like to get is a continuous series of dates with the hours that are valid at the moment.

E.g. **I would like to know the hours for each user and day between 2018-01-01 and 2019-02-28**, which would be

```
| id  | date       | user_id | hours |
| ..  | 2018-01-27 | 1       | 4     |
| ..  | 2018-01-28 | 1       | 4     |
| ..  | 2018-01-29 | 1       | 4     |
| ..  | 2018-01-30 | 1       | 4     |
| ..  | 2018-01-31 | 1       | 4     |
| ..  | 2019-02-01 | 1       | 8     |
| ..  | 2019-02-02 | 1       | 8     |
| ..  | 2019-02-03 | 1       | 8     |
| ..  | 2019-02-04 | 1       | 8     |
           ...
| ..  | 2018-06-30 | 2       | 5     |
| ..  | 2018-07-01 | 2       | 5     |
| ..  | 2018-07-02 | 2       | 8     |
| ..  | 2018-07-03 | 2       | 8     |
           ...
```

I don't know how to *fill in the blanks*, as I would describe it. I've thought about creating a table just full of dates between 1900 and 2100, but I can't come up with an idea how to fill in the blanks using the date table.

I've read about generate_series, I've tried joining the data in different ways and I also tried to use PostgresSQL's window functions. But I don't know how.

I was the closest with the *date table*, but the problem was the if the latest row for a user has a date outside the range I want to make the query to, that won't show in the results. Here's the query I tried:

```
SELECT user_id, d.date, minutes

    FROM day d

    JOIN dayload dl

    ON dl.date = (
        SELECT MAX(date) from DAYLOAD where date <= d.date
    )
    order by d.date;
```

I joined the user table etc. to this relation, but when I apply the date range filtering to the query, those rows are left out that have the latest dayload outside the date range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select generate_series(date,
                       lead(date, 1, current_date) over (partition by user_id order by date) - interval '1 day',
                       interval '1 day'
                      ) as date,
       user_id, hours
from (values (1, '2019-01-27'::date, 1, 4),
             (2, '2019-02-01'::date, 1, 8),
             (3, '2018-06-30'::date, 2, 5)
     ) v(id, date, user_id, hours);
```

It is a "simple" application of `generate_series()`.  The `lead()` is getting the next date for the user.  The complication with subtracting one day and all that is so there are no overlaps on the days.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3d97cde780a2610305b334ab6011959b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You sir are my hero! I didn't have time to test it in my real database but this seems to be **exactly** what I wanted. The only _problem_ is that now I want to understand how this works. I read about the window function, and I think I get it. However, now that you put it inside the generate_series function, it feels a bit like _magic_. Anyhow, excellent work!

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have bit different requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476124/add-missing-month-in-result-with-values-from-previous-month
can you please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

So, had a bit of a play and came up with the following query which I think will do what you want:

```
with
    __users as(
        select distinct
            user_id
        from
            dayload
    )
select
    row_number() over(order by __users.user_id asc, gs.date asc) as id,
    gs.date::date,
    __users.user_id,
    coalesce(dayload.hours, max(hours) over(partition by __users.user_id order by gs.date asc), 0) as hours
from
    generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2019-02-28'::date, interval '1 day') as gs("date")
    cross join __users
    left join dayload using(date, user_id)
order by
    __users.user_id asc,
    gs.date asc;
```

---

Explanation of the query:

```
with
    __users as(
        select distinct
            user_id
        from
            dayload
    )
```

This is called a CTE, or **c**ommon **t**able **e**xpression, a simplistic explanation of it is to say it is basically an inline temporary table in this context. Be careful using them as they are exclusively stored in memory, so large data returns can cause excessive paging bringing your database to a crawl.

```
generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2019-02-28'::date, interval '1 day') as gs("date")
```

This is generating the blank dates between the first and second parameters passed in. This is where you define the date range you want to query on.

```
coalesce(dayload.hours, max(hours) over(partition by user_id order by date asc), 0) as hours
```

This is fetching the hours in the current row we have joined in dayload. If that is null, then it fetches the highest hours from dayload that previous rows have joined to. If that is null, it returns 0.

```
generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2019-02-28'::date, interval '1 day') as gs("date")
cross join __users
left join dayload using(date, user_id)
```

This first gets every date between '2018-01-01'::date and '2019-02-28'::date, then it cross joins onto our CTE from earlier.

Cross joining will join every record from both tables together with no filter. It is situationally useful, but bear in mind it will yield the number of records in each table multiplied together. Careless use can result in more records than your server has memory for.

Once it has cross joined (giving us every date and every user id) we left join onto dayload.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like the key thing here is building a relationship between the actual date and the previous changed date (let's call it target date).
My two cents is building a helper table that has two columns: actual date and target date.
Start with populating the helper table with the actual dates and the target date can be left blank. Then use an update query to populate the target dates:

```
update HelperTable set TargetDate = 
(select Date from YourOriginalTable where 
HelperTable.ActualDate >= YourOriginalTable.Date 
order by YourOriginalTable.Date desc limit 1)
```

This way you build a date relationship mentioned above. And then you can leverage this helper table to build your goal table. Or you can just add the TargetDate in your goal table and you have the option to remove the column later if you wish.