# Add missing month in result with values from previous month

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a result set with month as first column. Some of the month are missing in the result. I need to add previous month record as the missing month till last month.

Current data:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

I have a sql but instead of filling for just missing month it is taking every rows into account and populate it.

```
select 
to_char(generate_series(date_trunc('MONTH',to_date(period,'YYYYMMDD')+interval '1' month),
              date_trunc('MONTH',now()+interval '1' day), 
              interval '1' month) - interval '1 day','YYYYMMDD') as period, 
name,age,salary,rating
from( values ('20201205','Alex',35,100,'A+'),
            ('20210110','Alex',35,110,'A'),
            ('20210512','Alex',35,999,'A+'),
            ('20210625','Jhon',20,175,'B-'),
            ('20210922','Jhon',20,200,'B+')) v (period,name,age,salary,rating) order by 2,3,4,5,1;
```

Output of this query:

[image]

Can someone help in getting desired output.

Regards!!

Comment: Did you try with `group by`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a recursive cte like this:

```
with RECURSIVE ctetest as (SELECT * FROM (values ('2020-12-31'::date,'Alex',35,100,'A+'),
            ('2021-01-31'::date,'Alex',35,110,'A'),
            ('2021-05-31'::date,'Alex',35,999,'A+'),
            ('2021-06-30'::date,'Jhon',20,175,'B-'),
            ('2021-09-30'::date,'Jhon',20,200,'B+')) v (mth, emp, age, salary, rating)), 
cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(mth) AS mth, emp, age, salary, rating
    FROM ctetest
    GROUP BY emp, age, salary, rating
    UNION 
    SELECT COALESCE(n.mth, (l.mth + interval '1 day' + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date), COALESCE(n.emp, l.emp), 
    COALESCE(n.age, l.age), COALESCE(n.salary, l.salary), COALESCE(n.rating, l.rating)
    FROM cte l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ctetest n ON n.mth = (l.mth + interval '1 day' + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date 
                                AND n.emp = l.emp
    WHERE (l.mth + interval '1 day' + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date <= (SELECT MAX(mth) FROM ctetest)
)
SELECT * FROM cte order by 2, 1;
```

Note that although ctetest is not itself `recursive`, being only used to get the test data, if any cte among multiple ctes are `recursive`, you must have the recursive keyword after the `with`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join lateral` to fill the gaps and then `union all` with the original data.

```
WITH the_table (period, name, age, salary, rating) as ( values
  ('2020-12-01'::date, 'Alex', 35, 100, 'A+'),
  ('2021-01-01'::date, 'Alex', 35, 110, 'A'),  
  ('2021-05-01'::date, 'Alex', 35, 999, 'A+'),
  ('2021-06-01'::date, 'Jhon', 20, 100, 'B-'),  
  ('2021-09-01'::date, 'Jhon', 20, 200, 'B+')
),
t as (
 select *, coalesce(
    lead(period) over (partition by name order by period) - interval 'P1M',
    max(period) over ()
   ) last_period
 from the_table
)
SELECT lat::date period, name, age, salary, rating
from t 
cross join lateral generate_series 
  (period + interval 'P1M', last_period, interval 'P1M') lat
UNION ALL
SELECT * from the_table
ORDER BY name, period;
```

Please note that using `integer` data type for a date column is sub-optimal. Better review your data design and use `date` data type instead. You can then *present* it as integer if necessary.

| period | name | age | salary | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | Alex | 35 | 100 | A+ |
| 2021-01-01 | Alex | 35 | 110 | A |
| 2021-02-01 | Alex | 35 | 110 | A |
| 2021-03-01 | Alex | 35 | 110 | A |
| 2021-04-01 | Alex | 35 | 110 | A |
| 2021-05-01 | Alex | 35 | 999 | A+ |
| 2021-06-01 | Alex | 35 | 999 | A+ |
| 2021-07-01 | Alex | 35 | 999 | A+ |
| 2021-08-01 | Alex | 35 | 999 | A+ |
| 2021-09-01 | Alex | 35 | 999 | A+ |
| 2021-06-01 | Jhon | 20 | 100 | B- |
| 2021-07-01 | Jhon | 20 | 100 | B- |
| 2021-08-01 | Jhon | 20 | 100 | B- |
| 2021-09-01 | Jhon | 20 | 200 | B+ |